# Selecting duplicate rows while maintaining original record

Tags: mysql

I have a query I wrote that looks like this:

```
SELECT t.oid AS order_id, t.email 
FROM test AS t, `test-count` AS tc 
WHERE t.`email` = tc.`email`
```

It outputs something like this:

```
ID  |  order_id  |   email
1        1          a@a.com
2        2          a@a.com
3        3          a@a.com
4        4          a@a.com
5        5          b@a.com
6        6          b@a.com
7        7          b@a.com
8        8          b@a.com
```

Now, What I am trying to do, is select all the records which are not the original. An example would be up top `ID 1` and `ID 5` are the original orders (both orders are the very first instance of the email. I would like to disregard those orders from showing up in my query.

I am attempting to track down and refund some orders but do not want to refund the original order, only the duplicate order.

Comment: How do you decide that order with ID 2 is a duplicate of order with ID 1, based on the email address alone?

Comment: If you're selecting 2 fields, then why does the output have 3? Can you show the data of each of the tables?

Comment: @MostyMostacho the ID is for reference in this question

Comment: @Vikdor because I am working with exported data for which I asked specifically for only duplicate orders.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a a not IN clause to exclude the min result:

```
SELECT t.oid AS order_id, t.email 
FROM test AS t, `test-count` AS tc 
WHERE t.`email` = tc.`email`
AND t.oid NOT IN (SELECT MIN(t2.oid)
                  FROM test t2
                  WHERE t2.email = t.email
                  )
```

Comment: This seems to cause a never ending query?

Comment: You can check here for a similar example on your data that you showed: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3543e/3. Not sure what is the problem

Comment: Would it be possible that My issue is because I am using a join, and your example is not?

Comment: Can't really tell. Usually the problem of hanging queries is about indexes. You should have one for oid at least.